# asigning INDEX in DBF from vb6

Tags: vb6, foxpro, dbf

I have a "users.dbf" table with the "users.cdx" index file it's a free table, so there is no dbc file. Both are located in the same folder. Sometimes when I add a new row in users.dbf, users.cdx is not updated, the link between dbf and cdx is broken. This table belongs to a third party app.
To solve this problem I use de command "USE ..\myfolder\users.dbf INDEX ..\myfolder\users.cdx" from a foxpro table viewer and the index file is linked again.
Is there any way to use this command from vb6?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code clipped from an old demo:

```
CN.Open "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source='" _
      & App.Path _
      & "';Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;Deleted=True"
With CN
    .Execute "ExecScript('USE DemoTable EXCLUSIVE" & vbCr _
           & "INDEX ON CustNumber TAG CustIX" & vbCr _
           & "INDEX ON DELETED() TAG DELETED BINARY')", _
             , _
             adCmdText Or adExecuteNoRecords
    'Resume sharing:
    .Execute "ExecScript('USE DemoTable SHARED')", _
             , _
             adCmdText Or adExecuteNoRecords
End With
```

Point being that you can use `ExecScript` for such things.